# Unknown 'transpose3x3' Error in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I must have made some coding mistake here because I've been tweaking this code and have had it run successfully for the last few weeks. Now it appears that I'm getting an error; I'm not quite sure why. The error disappears when I comment this line (124):

```
sphere(20);
```

The error appears as this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transpose3x3' of null
    at p5.Matrix.inverseTranspose (p5.js:31017)
    at p5.RendererGL._setMatrixUniforms (p5.js:31953)
    at p5.RendererGL.drawBuffers (p5.js:31676)
    at p5.sphere (p5.js:32444)
    at pointsSphereFibonacci (spheres_4.js:124)
    at draw (spheres_4.js:82)
    at p5.redraw (p5.js:14256)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:9143)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:9049)
    at new p5 (p5.js:9320)
```

Let me know if you have any ideas! Thank you!

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2, -1000);
}

var r = 800;
var n = 1024;
var lon = [];
var lat = [];
var i = 0;

function draw() {
  background(247, 147, 135);
  ambientLight(240, 240, 240);

  push();
  rotateY(-radians(frameCount * .1));
  rotateX(radians(90 + frameCount * .08));
  rotateZ(radians(180 + frameCount * .03));
  pointSphereFibonacci(r, n); // draw sphere equally spaced points
  pop();
}

function pointSphereFibonacci(radius, points) {
  var phi = (sqrt(5) + 1) / 2 - 1; // golden ratio
  var ga = phi * 2 * PI; // golden angle

  for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {

    lon[i] = ga * i;
    lon[i] /= 2 * PI;
    lon[i] -= floor(lon[i]);
    lon[i] *= 2 * PI;
    if (lon[i] > PI) {
      lon[i] -= 2 * PI;
    }
  }
  var lat = asin(-1 + 2 * i / points);

  for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {

    push();
    rotateY(lon[i]);
    rotateZ(-lat[i]);
    translate(radius, 0, 0);
    ambientMaterial(5, 0, 223);
    sphere(20);
    pop();

  }
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://p5js.org/assets/js/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of your entire project. If your problem is specific to that one line, then please post an example program that does not contain all the extra stuff like the microphone and the sound analysis code. Just use hard-coded values instead, so we can run it on our machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the call to `sphere` but in setting the translations of the sphere

you set `rotateZ(-lat[i]);` when `lat` is not an array but a number. That sends a NaN through the calculations that results in a fatal error when trying to render the sphere.

I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve, but changing that to `rotateZ(lat)` gets rid of the error and gives a visible result